# What happens if ctx.rip and ctx.rsp in a signal handler is modified

Tags: go, signals

As we all know that a program is interrupted by a signal and entering kernel space then switch to a userspace signal handler. After the signal handler is accomplished, it will be reentering the kernel space then switch back to where was interrupted.

I am recently reading the newly implemented async preemption in go 1.14, which uses the OS signal to interrupt a "non-preemptive" user goroutine. I am debugging very simple program:

```
package main

import (
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func tightloop() {
    for {
    }
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    go tightloop()

    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
    println("OK")
    runtime.Gosched()
}
```

In Go 1.14, when a preempt signal arrives, the `tightloop` will be interrupted by the OS and entering the pre-configured signal handler `runtime·sigtramp`:

```
TEXT runtime·sigtramp(SB),NOSPLIT,$72
    MOVQ    DX, ctx-56(SP)
    MOVQ    SI, info-64(SP)
    MOVQ    DI, signum-72(SP)
    MOVQ    $runtime·sigtrampgo(SB), AX
    CALL AX
    RET
```

which `sigtrampgo` eventually calls the `sighandler`.

```
//go:nosplit
//go:nowritebarrierrec
func sigtrampgo(sig uint32, info *siginfo, ctx unsafe.Pointer) {
    (...)
    setg(g.m.gsignal)
    (...)
    sighandler(sig, info, ctx, g)
    setg(g)
    (...)
}
```

As far as I read the `sighandler` function, it calls `doSigPreempt` and modifies the `ctx` that passed from system kernel, and sets the `rip` to the prologue of `runtime.asyncPreempt`.

```
//go:nowritebarrierrec
func sighandler(sig uint32, info *siginfo, ctxt unsafe.Pointer, gp *g) {
    _g_ := getg()
    c := &sigctxt{info, ctxt}

    (...)
    if sig == sigPreempt {
        doSigPreempt(gp, c)
    }
}
func doSigPreempt(gp *g, ctxt *sigctxt) {
    if canPreempt {
        // here modifies the rip and rsp
        ctxt.pushCall(funcPC(asyncPreempt))
    }

    (...)
}
```

However, I noticed that the asyncPreempt is not immediately executed when
the signal handler is complete, instead:

1. `morestack` or `morestack_noctxt` is called after `sighandler` is **returned** (not entering either the epilogue or prologue), which calls `newstack` and check checks the preempt flag and entering schedule loop and therefore schedules the main goroutine to finish the async preemption.
2. the `OK` outputs before executing `asyncPreempt`

Here is my inserted print logs in runtime:

```
mstart1 call schedule()
enter schedule()
park_m call schedule()
enter schedule()
mstart1 call schedule()
enter schedule()
mstart1 call schedule()
enter schedule()
park_m call schedule()
enter schedule()
park_m call schedule()
enter schedule()
park_m call schedule()
enter schedule()
mstart1 call schedule()
enter schedule()
park_m call schedule()
enter schedule()
rip: 17149264 eip: 824634034136
before pushCall asyncPreempt
after pushCall asyncPreempt
rip: 17124704 eip: 824634034128      // rip points to asyncPreempt
calling newstack: m0, g0             // how could newstack is called?
newstack call gopreempt_m
gopreempt_m call goschedImpl
goschedImpl call schedule()
enter schedule()
OK
gosched_m call goschedImpl
goschedImpl call schedule()
enter schedule()
asyncPreempt2
asyncPreempt2
asyncPreempt2
asyncPreempt2
preemptPark
gopreempt_m call goschedImpl
goschedImpl call schedule()
enter schedule()
```

while I checked the dumped assembly code, there are no stack split check
in neither `asyncPreempt` or `sigtramp`.

Sorry for the long story, my questions are:

- When, who, and how runtime calls the `morestack` after `sighandler`? What did I miss?
- Does modifying `ctx` changes program jumps to the modified `rip` instruction after finishing the signal handler?

Thank you very much for reading the question and thanks to the go team building such a brilliant feature.

Comment: I have not looked at the Go 1.14 code, but in general, the Linux/Unix signal handling system works by delivering a signal on the signal stack that the process has pre-set, or on the current stack if it did not pre-set a signal stack. To interrupt the running program, instead of having the kernel's own interrupt/fault-handler return to the user instruction that got interrupted/faulted, the kernel writes a kernel context to the signal stack frame, then sets the program counter(s) appropriately and "returns" to the user signal trampoline. This trampoline is responsible for (continued)

Comment: ... taking the signal and eventually using a `sigreturn` system call (or similar) to restore register values and go back to user code. Typically, to reschedule in a user-land scheduler, you would change the sigreturn data structure's saved PC(s) (and any other special registers) after first saving the interrupted PC(s) / registers so that the interrupted thing can be restored. In this case, that corresponds to setting the ctx `rip`, so it's more or less what you're suggesting.

Comment: @torek If I understand correctly, the kernel indeed can restore the modified registers and can start executing from somewhere else other than where was interrupted. If so then it becomes very interesting: the signal handler in Go runtime sets the `rip` to `asyncPreempt`, but not executing it after signal handler is returned. Instead, it calls `morestack`. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: I'd bet that there's some other boilerplate-y stuff somewhere that makes sure that the newly launched goroutine calls `morestack` first. Exactly where, well, that tends to be tricky.

Comment: @torek, this seems false. I checked the generated assembly, there is no prologue in `asyncPreempt` call, which means if the kernel restores to `asyncPreempt`, it should start calling it immediately.

Comment: The boilerplate may be elsewhere/elsewise: that ctx.rip might not be sent directly to the kernel, for instance. As I said, I haven't looked at the new 1.14 code (haven't even looked at the 1.13 code, actually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, many thanks to Ian's hint:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/BA7Dqp_zcwk

The root cause seems similar to the "uncertainty principle".

As an observer, by adding a `println` call in `asyncPreempt` 
as well as `asyncPreempt2` influences the actual behavior 
after signal handling. The `println` involves stack split check, 
which calls the `morestack`.

It took me a while to realize that `morestack` stores its caller 
pc in `g.m.morebuf.pc` since `getcallerpc` in `newstack` 
always returns the pc from `morestack`, which doesn't tell 
too much information.

```
//go:nosplit
func asyncPreempt2() {
    // println("asyncPreempt2 is called") // comment here omits calling morestack.
    gp := getg()
    gp.asyncSafePoint = true
    if gp.preemptStop {
        mcall(preemptPark)
    } else {
        mcall(gopreempt_m)
    }
    println("asyncPreempt2 finished")
    gp.asyncSafePoint = false
}
```

**TLDR: after signal handler, kernal restores `asyncPreempt`'s `rip` and directly switches to it, nothing happens between `runtime.asyncPreempt` and `runtime.sigtramp`.**